# Unable to open AWStats report page in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6, awstats

I have set this up before in linux and its a little different in IIS but I have a conf file that I've modified correctly and when I try to access the report page awstast.pl?config=myconfig its not find the webpage.  I can get to the directory the awstats.pl file is in but it won't show up.  Any Ideas?

Comment: We will need some information on how you configured IIS

Answer (score 0):

How do you know you modified it correctly?

And did you install Perl at any stage?